# Transforming a encryption of binary representation of a number to an encryption of vector representation

Tags: encryption, public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs, homomorphic-encryption

Suppose Alice chooses a number $n\in Z_q$ and decompose it to its binary representation $b_0,b_1,...,b_d$. Then Alice encrypts these bits (can be any encryption scheme). Is it possible for Bob (who does not have Alice's decryption key) to read these encrypted bits  and create a vector of size $q$ so that each entry is an encryption of $0$ except at index $n$ where there is an encryption of $1$. We cam assume that Alice can send to bob information (non interactively) of size at most log(n), while keeping the number $n$ private.

Answer (score 1):

If you use FHE then Alice can encrypt the bits $b_i, i \in [d]$, where $d$ is about $\log q$, send it to Bob, and then have Bob run a demultiplexer circuit. The output should be $q$ ciphertexts where all of them are encryptions of $0$ except one that encrypts $1$ at index $n$. A recursive definition can be found in Protocol 2 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/137.pdf, although the paper is about MPC, it can also be applied for FHE since this circuit only involves addition and multiplication.

A more recent paper also has a description of the demux circuit but in a procedural form, see Section 3.2 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/757.pdf

Comment: That is great. Thank you very much!